# "Origin null not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header"

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, cross-domain

In my Angular4 app I make a request to a WebApi2 controller. Both are currently running locally (on different ports).

I'm currently stuck getting this as a response:
*Origin null not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.*

My request and WebApi look like this:

**people-search.service.ts**

```
let people = this.http
    .get('http://localhost:4658/api/Users/?searchText=' + term)
    .map((r: Response) => {
        // do some stuff and return array
    });
```

**WebApi.Config.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute());

        config.EnableCors();

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.Add(new FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API", "api/{controller}");
    }
}
```

**UsersController.cs**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    ...
}
```

I now that there are lots of similar questions, but I haven't found an answer that helped me yet. What's strange here, is that it does not recognize the url but instead has an origin of "null". Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add your full code of `Register` for `WebApiConfig`? I assume that there is additional portion of the code above `config.EnableCors();`? `config.EnableCors();` Should be called first before defining your default routes configs.

Comment: sure, I have edited my question.

Comment: Are you using chrome and accessing local files for ajax by any chance? `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` means that you are trying to perform Ajax on a local file, this is forbidden for security reasons.

Comment: I am using Edge, actually. I have added the call I make in angular.

Comment: I just found out, that apparently it's not the backend (localhost:4658) generating the issue, but the Azure Active Directory Authentication integration. I think the request is being redirected to the login page and therefore the CORS error is thrown...